# Memory leak in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a class:

```
class Land{
public:
  ~Land() { if(map != nullptr) Clean(); }

  bool Create();
  void PrintMap() const;
  void Clean();
private:
  int rows = 0, columns = 0;
  int **map = nullptr;

  bool CorrectDimensions() const;
  void CreateMap();
  bool FillMap();
};
bool Land::Create() {
  //
  printf("Matrix size:\n");
  if(scanf("%d %d", &(this->columns), &(this->rows) ) != 2 || !CorrectDimensions() )
    return false;

  CreateMap();
  printf("Values:\n");
  return FillMap();
}
void Land::CreateMap() {
  //
  this->map = new int*[rows];

  for(int column = 0; column < this->rows; column++)
    map[column] = new int[this->columns];
}
bool Land::FillMap() {
  //
  for(int row = 0; row < this->rows; row++) {
    for(int column = 0; column < this->columns; column++) {
      if( ! scanf("%d", &(this->map[row][column]) ) ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}
void Land::Clean() {
  //
  for(int row = 0; row < this->rows; row++)
  delete [] this->map[row];
  delete [] this->map;
}
```

And my driver:

```
int main() {
  //
  Land l;

  if( ! l.Create() ) {
    IncorrectInput();
    return 1;
  }

  l.PrintMap(); //prints correct output
}
```

How I imagine my program should work:

1. Default constructor gets called, no need for a custom one.
2. Check if the input satisfies the requirements. **If not**, return `false` thus finishing the program. Memory hasn't been dynamically allocated yet (stays at `nullptr`), no problem.
3. If yes, **create a 2D array** using `calloc` (I know I'm mixing C with C++, wanted to use class and `vector` is not available).
4. Fill that 2D array with scanned values. If scanned values aren't ints, return false, thus finishing the program.
5. Print the value of that array. Const function.
6. Finish the program so destructor is called. Since I don't know if `Create()` ended prematurely (before `calloc`) or not, I default initialize `int **map` to `nullptr`. If I allocate, `map` won't be `nullptr` anymore and will need to be freed. Otherwise, destructor should `free`, that's what `Clean()` does.
7. `Clean()` I followed the practices of dynamic allocation and freeing. `calloc` and `free` follow their reversed patterns. Debugging confirmed that how many `calloc`s were called, that many `free`s were called.

With all of this, `valgrind` still reports errors (not `reachable`, actual errors). Specifically: `total heap usage: 184 allocs, 23 frees`. What caused this error, what have I missed?

EDIT: Initialized `rows` and `columns` members. Changed `calloc()` with C++ `new` and `delete`.

Comment: `calloc` and `free` in C++?

Comment: @John3136 see `(I know I'm mixing C with C++, wanted to use class and vector is not available).`

Comment: Doesn't stop you using `new` and `delete`

Comment: Your program will leak memory in a whole variety of ways, even if you "fix" the problem.  What if in the middle of the creation of your matrix, one of the calls to `calloc` fails?  How are you going to recover that memory?

Comment: @John3136 Reworked using `new` and `delete`. Valgrind reports identical error.

Comment: Also, something as simple as `{Land l; }` invokes undefined behavior due to the member variables not being initialized in the `Land` object, and the destructor will be called using an uninitialized `rows` and `map` values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I should've checked after every calloc. Still, this isn't the problem of this case or is it?

Comment: Interesting fun fact: What you are creating is an array of arrays, not a 2D array. For an interesting take on how to make a 2D array give the following FAQ entry on making a matrix a read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: What is this `IncorrectInput`? Does it trigger an exception or terminate the program?

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh -- I suggest getting rid of the input routines that return prematurely if someone enters a wrong value.  Make sure the basic things do not leak first.   Right now, there are fundamental problems with your design, as pointed out by my comment.

Comment: @user4581301Just prints error message.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. (Anyone know an online valgrind?)  Might be something silly happening in the code that hasn't been provided. Unrelated: `this->map = (int**)calloc( (size_t)this->rows, sizeof(int*) );` `calloc` is pointless here. You are about to overwrite all of the pointers in the next loop.

Comment: @user4581301 Just tried using valgrind in [**CS50's IDE**](http://cs50.io) and there valgrind showed no memory leaks. So is it possible my valgrind (MacOS Sierra) is causing problems?

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh -- Your updated code will cause a memory leak if `new` throws an exception in the middle of that loop.  If you want to duplicate the issue, give a very large number to `rows` and `columns`.  So no matter how you changed your code, you're right back at the situation where leaks will occur.  If you insist on doing things this way, then [this way of allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048) gives you a fighting chance to rollback the previous allocations if `new` throws, as there are only 2 allocations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory-leak.
`calloc` doesn't throw exception.

BTW, Null-pointer deference is detected in `Land::CreateMap` and meny other places.
Don't forget checking returned value of `calloc`

## updated

For example,

```
class foo {
  int* p1;
  int* p2;
  foo()
  {
    p1 = new int;
    p2 = new int;
  }
  ~foo()
  {
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
  }
};
int main()
{
  foo val;
}
```

In Ctor of `foo`, when `p2 = new int;` throw exception, Dtor of `foo` **will not called**, so, Anyone can delete `p1`!

So, when you want to allocate memory with non-noexcept operator `new` in ctor, You must use RAII wrapper. C++11 or later has RAII wapper class to allocate memory, that is `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

BTW,

> vector is not available

What's the environment are you using?

Comment: If there is no memory leak, how should I interpret `valgrind`'s output?

Comment: wait, wait Wait, WAIT! Your updated code that using `new` will cause memory leak!!

Comment: It produced literally the same output as with calloc.

Comment: I think you need to expand on your argument, yumetodo. Either I am misunderstanding it or you have based it around a flawed assumption.